# Analogue of a "perfect" polynomial fit in $\mathbb{R}^p$, $p > 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I can't find a source for this right now - and it's been years since I've taken Linear Algebra - but my recollection is that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if you have $n$ points with distinct $x$ values, there exists a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ which goes through all of those $n$ points. (Just found a source: I guess this is called the [Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html).)

Is there an analogue of this theorem in $\mathbb{R}^p$, $p > 2$?

Google searching has led me to nothing, and I *definitely* haven't read about this in my plethora of textbooks at home.

Comment: you mean with polynomials on more than one variable?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a polynomial that works, but I am not sure if it the "best" one.

Let the $n$ points be $p_1,p_2\dots p_n$ with $p_j=(a_{j,1},a_{j,2}\dots a_{j,d})$. And suppose we want to find a polynomial $P$ with $P(p_j)=b_j$.

Notice that the polynomial $P_j=(x_1-a_{j,1})^2+(x_2-a_{j,2})^2+\dots+(x_d-a_{j,d})^2$ is only zero at the point $p_j$

Therefore the polynomal $Q_j=P_1P_2\dots P_{j-1}P_{j+1}\dots P_n$ is zero at every point $p_k$ except $p_j$

So the polynomial $P=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}Q_j\times(\frac{b_j}{Q_j(p_j)})$ satisfies $P(p_j)=b_j$ for all $j$.